# How to access GraphqlServer Context Object when I add curly braces to be able to add more elements to the context?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, graphql

I am working with GraphQL, Graphql-yoga and NodeJS.

I have problems accessing my DB array when is nested within my GraphQLServer context. Everything works fine when my GraphQLServer context is configured with a single element as shown here: (db is an array to simulate DB content).

[image]

When I add curly braces to it, it breaks:

[image]

Even if i don't see any error while coding, when trying to execute any of my resolvers seems they cannot access the DB object anymore and all my find(), findIndex(), some() and all the methods that are associated to my DB array are not working anymore. If I set back to: context: db everything works perfectly.

This is the error I get when running
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined

This is how my resolver looks like:

[image]

Even if I destrcuture context to work directly with the array in my resolver I still get the same error:

[image]

This is my package.json:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for that -1? Leaving a -1 and not leaving a reason for it doesn't help me to improve my question for other people to find it useful. I would appreciate some feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
const context = db
```

then you are setting the value of context to whatever the value of `db` is. If you did that and then ran the following code

```
context.db.comments.findIndex(comment => comment.id === args.id)
```

that would mean there is a property named `db` on the `context` object. Because `context` is the same as your original `db` variable, that would mean there was a property named `db` on the original `db` variable. So this code would work too if you used the `db` variable directly:

```
db.db.comments.findIndex(comment => comment.id === args.id)
```

If instead of setting `context` to `db` you set its value to a new object with a property named `db` and then set the value of that property to `db`

```
context = { db: db }
```

or using shorthand notation:

```
context = { db }
```

then your function call would now look like this:

```
context.db.db.comments.findIndex(comment => comment.id === args.id)
```

Comment: This is absolutely right and solved my problem. I spent so much time trying to figure this out. Appreciate your time to help me. Cheers.